# How to SOQL query a Filtered Lookup on same Object?

Tags: soql, relationships

I am trying to a subQuery for records of a specific Opportunity type that lookup via a Filtered Lookup, 'parent' Opportunities of another record type.

This is the latest subquery tried so far:

```
SELECT Name,Id, (SELECT Primary_Media_Opportunity__c FROM Opportunity.MSA_Lookup__r) 
FROM Opportunity
WHERE (RecordTypeId = '012U0000000a3NM')
```

the MSA_Lookup__c is the filtered Lookup field for the child Opportunity record type, but when I tried querying, this error was returned:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity.MSA_Lookup__r' in FROM
>   part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom
>   relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
>   relationship name.

Is there a syntax for subQuerying child records of the same object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use child relationship name in the subquery .

For the filtered lookup field there will be a child relationship name .

The subquery will use child relationship name with __r.Let's say your child relationship name is MSA_lookups then your inner query will be

Select id,(Select primary_media__c from MSA_lookups__r) from opportunity

Comment: Thanks! However, I tried that and the error returned "didn't understand relationship 'MSA_Lookup__r' in FROM part of query call." 
My new subquery: 
SELECT Name,Id, (SELECT Primary_Media_Opportunity__c FROM MSA_Lookup__r) FROM Opportunity

Comment: What is child relationship name listed on your field ?

Comment: It was MSA_Opportunities-- I changed the inner query to use that field name, and the query successfully found the records! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool.Glad you figured it out!